# Alfresco cron syntax: difference between 0/2 and */2?

Tags: java, cron, alfresco

Alfresco has a cron-like system that allows you to run a job at regular intervals. [The documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-scheduled-jobs.html) specifies as an example the expression `0 0/2 * * * ?` which will make the job run every 2 minutes. However, in a lot of code I see people using the expression `0 */2 * * * ?` instead, the difference being that the zero is replaced by an asterisk. This syntax is more similar to the [syntax found in some Unix implementations of cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Non-Standard_Characters), but I don't think I can blindly assume they work the same (Alfresco's syntax has a *seconds* field that Unix syntax lacks, for instance).

So my question is, is there any difference in functionality between the expression `0/2` and `*/2`? And as a followup, is there a place where Alfresco's syntax is properly documented?

Comment: [These docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/sync-props.html) link through to a [Quartz tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger), implying that they use Quartz to implement their scheduling (and thus that those docs should be considered canonical).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth)'s comment led me to the [Quartz docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html#special-characters) that contain the answer:

> You can also specify ‘/’ after the ‘*’ character - in this case ‘*’ is equivalent to having ‘0’ before the ‘/’.

So `0/2` and `*/2` are equivalent cron expressions.